Erro Status code 400 ao atualizar as classes JWTUtils e WebSecurityConfig para Java23 e Gradle 8.10
Estou atualizando uma API em SpringBoot de Java 8 e Gradle 5.6.2 para as versões 23 do Java e 8.10 do Gradle. Sendo assim, foi necessário que eu modificasse as classes JWTUtils e WebSecurityConfig. Porém quando fiz essa atualização, após ser autenticado no sistema e realizar alguma requisição ele me retorna "Request failed with status code 400".
Segue a implementação nova das classes mencionadas.
 @Component
 public class JwtUtils {
 
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);
 
     private final long jwtExpirationMs = 864_000_00;
 
     private final String jwtSecret = "signingKey";
 
     public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
         UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
 
         try {
             Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
             return JWT.create()
                     .withSubject(userPrincipal.getUsername())
                     .withIssuedAt(Date.from(Instant.now()))
                     .withExpiresAt(Date.from(generateExpirationDate()))
                     .sign(algorithm);
         } catch (JWTCreationException exception) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Error while generating JWT token", exception);
         }
     }
 
     public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
         try {
             Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
             return JWT.require(algorithm)
                     .build()
                     .verify(token)
                     .getSubject();
         } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
             logger.error("Error while verifying JWT token: {}", exception.getMessage());
             return null;
         }
     }
 
     public boolean validateJwtToken(String token) {
         try {
             Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
             JWT.require(algorithm)
                     .build()
                     .verify(token);
             return true;
         } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
             logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", exception.getMessage());
             return false;
         }
     }
 
     private Instant generateExpirationDate() {
         return LocalDateTime.now().plusNanos(jwtExpirationMs * 1_000_000).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
     }
 }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    
//    @Autowired
//    private ImplementsUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
//     
    @Autowired
    private BlackListService bllist;
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServicesImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
      
 @Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) // Desativa CSRF
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())) // Desativa CORS (se necessário ativar, configure um CorsConfigurationSource)
        .sessionManagement(session -> 
            session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)) // Define sessão como stateless
        .exceptionHandling(exception -> 
            exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)) // Define handler para exceções de autenticação
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> 
            authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/signUp", "/auth/signin", "/auth/forgotPass", "/login", "/token", "/error/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/isAlive").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // Qualquer outra requisição deve estar autenticada
        )
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) // Adiciona o filtro JWT
        .logout(logout -> 
            logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)) // Configura comportamento do logout
        );

    return http.build(); // Constrói e retorna a cadeia de segurança
}

    
   @Bean
   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();  
       CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();  
       config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000",
"localhost:4200"));  
       config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));  
       config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));  
       config.setAllowCredentials(true);  
       config.applyPermitDefaultValues();  
 
       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);  
       return source; 
   }
    

}

Abaixo a implementação antiga.


@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    
    static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 864_000_00;  
    static final String SIGNINGKEY = "signingKey";  
  
    

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SIGNINGKEY)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SIGNINGKEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SIGNINGKEY).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000",
"localhost:4200"})
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
//    @Autowired
//    private ImplementsUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
//     
    @Autowired
    private BlackListService bllist;
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServicesImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/signUp").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/signin").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/forgotPass").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/token").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/error/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/isAlive").permitAll()
            
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED));
    
    }
    
   @Bean
   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();  
       CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();  
       config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));  
       config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));  
       config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));  
       config.setAllowCredentials(true);  
       config.applyPermitDefaultValues();  
 
       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);  
       return source; 
   }
    
    }



